# How to build clang + LLVM with non system gcc

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm

I am trying to switch to gcc47+ setup in `/usr/local/bin/gcc`. The default system gcc is 4.4.6 in `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Similarly header files :

`/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/bits/stl_pair.h
/usr/local/include/c++/4.7.1/bits/stl_pair.h`

I tried to build llvm clang with `cd /apps/llvmbuild ; /apps/llvm/configure --prefix=/apps/llvmbuild --enable-optimized --enable-cxx11 --enable-docs=no --enable-targets=host-only --disable-assertions CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/ CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/`

And then
`cd /apps/llvmbuild ; make -j12 ENABLE_OPTIMIZED=1 DISABLE_ASSERTIONS=1`

but I am getting errors that show it is searching for c++ files in the 4.4.6 directory :
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/exception_ptr.h`

```
locate exception_ptr.h
/usr/include/c++/4.4.4/exception_ptr.h
/usr/local/include/c++/4.7.1/bits/exception_ptr.h
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **CC** and **CXX** environment variables.
See `configure --help` for info:

```
Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  ...
  CXX         C++ compiler command

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.
```

Something like this:

```
CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++ CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc /apps/llvm/configure --your --other --options
```